# Pthread library cleanup of detached threads

Tags: pthreads

I'm trying to figure out how NPTL cleans up the resources (stack space, etc) of a
detached thread when it exits. Joinable threads are easy, there's a call to pthread_join
which waits for a specific thread to exit and then reclaims its resources. No problem, but
how does NPTL know that a detached thread has exited? Does anyone know or at least know who
would know?

thanks,
Rich

Answer (score 0):

after the thread function returns, NPTL will check whether the thread is detached, if it is detached, it will free everything of the thread directly, if it is joined, it will leave thread control block(TCB) to pthread_join to free TCB.

for detail, http://raison.gegahost.net/?p=91 may helps.

Comment: Ah, this is what I was looking for. So pthread_create is passed the executor function and this function is wrapped with a helper function and the helper function is passed to the clone system call. The helper function is responsible for cleaning up a detached thread. Thanks very much.